# Can I run another batch file in the current batch file windows?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example, if I have two batch files, A1 and A2, within the same folder and I want to load A2 from A1, like the following code:

```
::This is a program loader
::A2.bat is another batch file within the same folder
title A1
@echo off
choice /m "Do you wish to proceed?"
if errorlevel 1 start A2.bat
if errorlevel 2 exit
```

I know it will just open A2.bat in a new window, but is there anyway that I can open A2.bat in the existing window of A1.bat? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `call` instead of `start`:

```
::This is a program loader
::A2.bat is another batch file within the same folder
title A1
@echo off
choice /m "Do you wish to proceed?"
if errorlevel 1 CALL A2.bat
if errorlevel 2 exit
```

Answer (score -2):

`start /b A2.bat` will run A2.bat without creating a new window

Comment: Why the downvotes? This answer is closer to the original OP's question than the `call` one!

Comment: @Aacini - I did not down vote, but I presume the down voters assume the OP does not want the script to run in parallel, even though that is what the OP's original code did. The CALL solution is more typically what is needed, but, as you say, this answer better aligns with the original code (for better or for worse).